# Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server.SqlRestore timeout issues

Tags: database, powershell, restore

I have a script that I created a powershell script based on a script I found, [Start-Migration](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Use-PowerShell-to-Migrate-86c841df). It is a great script and gave me a lot of really good ideas; however I am running into some issues when attempting to restore large databases or databases that take longer than 10 minutes. I have attempted to use both them invoke-sqlcmd2 function I found and the class for the restore for the microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo namespace. both of which are timing out after 10 minutes. I have also tried increasing the connection timeout even setting the connection to 1200. any suggestions would be welcomed.

```
Function Restore-SQLDatabase {
    <#
        .SYNOPSIS
            Restores .bak file to SQL database. Creates db if it doesn't exist. $filestructure is
            a custom object that contains logical and physical file locations.

        .EXAMPLE
            $filestructure = Get-SQLFileStructures $sourceserver $destserver $ReuseFolderstructure
            Restore-SQLDatabase $destserver $dbname $backupfile $filestructure   

        .OUTPUTS
            $true if success
            $true if failure
    #>
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [object]$server,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$dbname,


        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$backupfile,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [object]$filestructure

    )

$servername = $server.Name
$server.ConnectionContext.StatementTimeout = 0
$restore = New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Restore"

foreach ($file in $filestructure.databases[$dbname].destination.values) {
    $movefile = New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile" 
    $movefile.LogicalFileName = $file.logical
    $movefile.PhysicalFileName = $file.physical
    $null = $restore.RelocateFiles.Add($movefile)
}

Write-Host "Restoring $dbname to $servername" -ForegroundColor Yellow

try{
      $Percent = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.PercentCompleteEventHandler]{
      Write-Progress -Id 1 -Activity "Restoring $dbname to $ServerName" -PercentComplete $_.Percent -Status ([System.String]::Format("Progress: {0}%",$_.Percent))
    }
    $restore.add_PercentComplete($Percent)
    $restore.PercentCompleteNotification = 1
    $restore.add_Complete($Complete)
    $restore.ReplaceDatabase = $true
    $restore.Database = $dbname
    $restore.Action = "Database"
    $restore.NoRecovery = $false
    $device = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.BackupDeviceItem
    $device.Name = $backupfile
    $device.DeviceType = "File"
    $restore.Devices.Add($device)


    Write-Progress -Id 1 -Activity "Restoring $dbname to $servername" -PercentComplete 0 -Status([System.String]::Format("Progress: {0}%",0))

    $restore.SqlRestore($servername)

    # $query = $restore.Script($ServerName)

    # Write-Host $query

    # Invoke-Sqlcmd2 -ServerInstance $servername -Database master -Query $query -ConnectionTimeout 1200

    # Write-Host "Restoring $dbname to $servername from " $restore.Devices.ToString() -ForegroundColor Magenta

    Write-Progress -Id 1 -Activity "Restore $dbname to $servername" -Status "Complete" -Completed

    return $true 
}
catch{

    Write-Error $_.Exception.ToString()

    Write-Warning "Restore failed: $($_.Exception.InnerException.Message)"

    return $false
}
```

when the restore process takes place ,$restore.SqlRestore($ServerName), on my larger databases it returns saying that the script timed out. I am trying to figure out how to correct this. I have tried increasing the statementtimeout = 1200 and it still stops after 10 minutes. i even attempted to us an invoke-sqlcmd As you can see I commented it out when trying different options. I am at wits end right now.

Comment: We'd love to help you, but you need to post your whole script here, and then try to describe what is going wrong in greater detail.

Comment: I edited the post. I just need help finding a way to restore SQL Databases using a script. The current code as you see using powershell/Smo, but when the database takes longer than 10 minutes to restore, it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I got it to work. I am not completely sure why it worked but here is what I did. I created a parameter $Server as follows:

`$Server = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server $Source
        $Server.ConnectionContext.ConnectTimeout = 0`

Now when I call the function that actually does the restore, I was doing something that I didn't need to do:

```
$ServerName = $server.Name
```

instead of using the $ServerName, I used the object $server:

```
$restore.SqlRestore($servername) # Original Script
$restore.SqlRestore($server) # Change
```

and now it stays open long enough to complete the restore process.

Answer (score 2):

**If you have to use the script you found**

I think that this line `$server.ConnectionContext.StatementTimeout = 0' is not actually doing anything or changing the timeout threshold.

Try changing the line to this, instead

```
$server = New-Object("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server") $server
$server.ConnectionContext.StatementTimeout = 0
$server.ConnectionContext.Connect()
```

However, I would recommend avoiding this approach entirely, because you can use the much much easier SQLPS Cmdlets.  The approach you're using comes from a long time ago, in which we didn't have actual PowerShell cmdlets to work with SQL.

Nowadays, we have the Restore-SQLDatabase cmdlet, which lets you do with one line what your code now is doing in ~30 lines!!

**How to Use Restore-SQLDatabase instead**

This is so much easier, and you'll really thank me, I think.

```
Restore-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance "$server\InstanceName" `
 -Database $dbname `-BackupFile $BackupFile
```

and...that's it.  One single line!  And you can also specify the timeout easily here, unlike before.  To specify the maximum timeout:

```
Restore-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance "$server\InstanceName" `
 -Database $dbname -BackupFile $BackupFile -ConnectionTimeout 0
```

That should get you started.  Trust me, using the Cmdlets is so much easier than using some random script you find online.

Comment: Will I be able to make use of a relocate file type of function?

Comment: @mqbk that's been my reoccurring issue. I've chosen to use SMO more due to the relocate files requiring some SMO work anyway, as well as the flexibility to restore a database as a new name (that might be done in cmdlet, but I can't recall how)